# Selenium download not working with Anaconda

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda

Trying to download selenium into my Anaconda packages, but it has not been working.  However, it has worked when I downloaded it to an environment.  I am trying to run a python script using selenium created in Sublime Text 3.  If for some reason I have to use the environment I created, how will I run the script through that versus/activate the environment prior to running the script.  I am quite new to python, so please correct me if anything I am saying is wrong.  Thanks.

[image: picture of what is happening in the command prompt after conda install -c conda-forge selenium]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Selenium directly using pip if it is installed.
I suggest that you create a conda virtual environment, which also installs pip by default. Then you can simply install selenium using pip.
Roughly the steps are like given below:

```
conda create -n env_name python=3
activate env_name
pip install selenium
```